# How can I access all constructors from a Groovy AST transformation?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing an AST transformation intended to keep a bidirectional JPA relationship in sync by making the setter on the referenced side also call the setter on the owning side. This works reliably when calling `setFoo()`, but a variable initialized in the constructor (because of a initializer statement in the declaration, a `new` in the constructor, or a constructor parameter) won't be linked.

To handle this case, I can open up all of the existing constructors (plus any implicit default constructor) and add the necessary code. However, some common AST transformations that add constructors, such as `@TupleConstructor`, run in the `CANONICALIZATION` phase, and there's no phase after that where I can reliably insert new instructions.

How can I ensure that my extra code is added to each constructor, including ones that may be added by other transformations?

Comment: I don't think that there is a defined order of the transformations within a compilation phase.

Comment: @cjstehno That's the potential race. I'm wondering if there's any practical workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here isn't to alter all the constructors but rather to use an object initializer block, which is copied to the end of all constructors. There's a minor unsafe-publication risk if the cooperating class does something foolish, but it's the same risk as adding the statement to the end of constructors explicitly.

The way to do this is:

```
classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(assignS(target, value));
```